# Is there a way to "spread" or "flatten" a GraphQL response?

Tags: graphql

I have a GraphQL query that looks like this

```
{
  allContentfulDocuments {
    edges {
      node {
        documents {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to flatten the `edges` and `node` layers, into something that essentially works like this query would:

```
{
  allContentfulDocuments {
    documents {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are using Relay, right? Then no, those are needed for it.

Comment: I am not quite sure, to be honest. We're using GatsbyJS and Contentful, don't know what's going on under the hood there.

Comment: Probably it's Relay. Edges and nodes are needed for cursor, pagination, etc... GraphQL itself does not specify anything about those fields. You could write this like `{documents {id}}`

Comment: It's `contentful` that is using edges and nodes (for Relay, ya) ;)

Comment: Can't you just process the response in JS?

Comment: I can (and do, for now), but I was curios if there was another solution.

Comment: I have the same question—keeping these in seems didactic and not actually practical since I will always just parse them out.

Comment: https://github.com/chasingmaxwell/graphql-leveler

Answer (score -1):

I know this answer is 4 years late but I just came across this problem.

This seemed to work for me:

```js
    const flattenGqlEdges = (edges) => edges.map((edge) => edge.node);
    flattenedData = flattenGqlEdges(data.allContentfulDocuments.edges)
```

For anyone that needs this in future :)

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve this by using `Array.prototype.map`.

```
data.allContentfulDocuments.edges.map(edge => 
  edge.node.documents.map(document => ({ id: document.id }))
```