# How to use GraphQL aliases to remove unwanted data?

Tags: graphql

As you can see from the below, I am trying to get GraphQL to remove "DEPARTMENT_CODE" from the response and just have the "DEPARTMENT_CODE" be the value for department_id

```
query data {
  investment_manager_report {
    department_id: department {
      DEPARTMENT_CODE
    }
  }
}
```

The above graphql query returns the below

```
{
  "data": {
    "investment_manager_report": [
      {
        "department_id": {
          "DEPARTMENT_CODE": "L"
        }
      },
      {
        "department_id": {
          "DEPARTMENT_CODE": "E"
        }
      },
      {
        "department_id": {
          "DEPARTMENT_CODE": "Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "department_id": {
          "DEPARTMENT_CODE": "B"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

but I want it to return the below

```
{
  "data": {
    "investment_manager_report": [
      {
        "department_id": "L"
      },
      {
        "department_id": "E"
      },
      {
        "department_id": "Z"
      },
      {
        "department_id": "B"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to simplify graphql response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54251285/how-to-simplify-graphql-response)

Comment: Apparently, this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47590134/is-there-a-way-to-spread-or-flatten-a-graphql-response - is even older, has more votes etc. But the answers there, with all due respect, were written without paying attention to the _real_ OP's intent, and graphql-leveler was only mentioned in the very last comment to the question (so one has to really search for it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be an intentional restriction of GraphQL approach to force clients into getting the response shaped "by graph".

And yes, in some way this limitation might seem to be kind of a reminiscence of old "want banana, get all the jungle with gorilla holding that banana" adage - only this time you're fetching just the keys of that dataset, and not really the whole universe. Some see this as a fair trade-off between (forced) readability and performance. Some have other opinions.

While there are external tools to overcome this limitation ([graphql-leveler](https://github.com/chasingmaxwell/graphql-leveler) is one of the most frequently mentioned here at SO in [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54251285/how-to-simplify-graphql-response) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61199378/reducing-output-of-graphql)), these tools' development is, by definition, not aligned with the way GraphQL is developed.

The other approach is to create some kind of "in-front" graph transformer that'll reduce the shape of the response to the way your specific client(s) seems fit. Apparently, this has all the typical pros and cons of using a reverse proxy.